# Reload div content without page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, refresh

How can I reload a div when a reset button is clicked?

Only the div content in tab should be reloaded.

I have tried as in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd3YZ/506/) however I am getting error

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

or sometimes is not displayed properly

How can I achieve reload div content without reloading whole page?

Answer (score 2):

If the content comes up from server side processing, then something like this should work
    $('#targetDiv').load('http://yourserver.com/test.html');

Check out this post as well http://api.jquery.com/load/

If the content is locally computed, then set its innerHTML property?

Comment: I have tried your approach, however in tab, whole page is loaded inside tab. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qd3YZ/510/) demo

Comment: I looked at the demo - unfortunately could not understand what you wanted. Can we simplify the problem?
Do you want to load new content inside a div that is actually loaded inside another div (which in turn was loaded via ajax?)

IF that is what you want, then the solution I wrote should still work - for the #targetDiv use the id of the inner Div.

Please help focus only the problem area.